# Status of Package Deployed in OSGi Bundle of AEM 6.0 is Active but Having Concern upon Usage

Tags: java, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I deployed a package in OSGi bundle of AEM 6.0 which has a status of Active. But when I tried to use it run-time in a certain page, it shows some exception:

```
05.06.2015 18:12:29.460 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1433499148835] GET /content/g0/en/about-us/career/jobs.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/namespace/QName
...
....
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.namespace.QName not found by com.**.wcm.recruitment-client [499]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1557)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 240 common frames omitted
```

I tried to manipulate the Import-Package and Export-Package under pom.xml but still concern persists.

See below for the XML that I am trying to manipulate.

```
    <plugin>
    ...
    ...
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.**.recruitment.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        **<Import-Package>
                        !javax.xml.namespace,*
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                        com.**.recruitment.client,
                        com.**.recruitment.ws
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
      ...
      ...
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instruction: `<Import-Package>!javax.xml.namespace, *</Import-Package>`
avoids package `javax.xml.namespace` being imported which is the opposite you need. Just remove `!`

Make sure javax.xml.namespace package is exported in your OSGi environment: It should be by default in any case you can try by setting this environment variable:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.xml.namespace;<other  packages>
```

Comment: Even better, don't set `Import-Package` explicitly at all, just let the tool work it out for you!

Comment: Also, why are you claiming to export `javax.xml.namespace`? It should not be in your bundle.

Comment: I meant it must be exported by other bundle or available in the system.

Comment: The reason i did that becasue of this previous concern  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498112/package-installed-in-aem-6-0-web-console-bundles-osgi-bundles-is-not-installin/30619518#30619518

Comment: Hi @BJHargrave, it not really there, i just experiment it since im trying to figure out why im having that kind of concern.

Comment: Hi @JorgeMartinez, where can i actually put "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.xml.namespace;", am i going to create one new file for these (*.properties) or in OSGi defualt configuration file/s?

Comment: That depends on the OSGi framework you are using. In the end you have to make sure the property is set as System variable: ```-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.pacakages.extra=javax.xml.namespace```